# How to make a block display to get parameters from URL?

Tags: views

I'm using a block display of a View to show some content of several taxonomies. I want to use contextual filters to display content of only one taxonomy when in the URL is the taxonomy id.

By doing some testing in the preview it works fine (it shows different content according to the taxonomy used to test) but when I test in the page it doesn't work. I could try several taxonomies ids in the URL and the view will keep displaying the same content.

Example of my situation:

www.domain.com/mainPage -> This shows a block display with content of several taxonomies
www.domain.com/mainPage/taxonomyId -> This continues displaying the same content of the several taxonomies.

Comment: is `/mainPage/taxonimyId` an alias of a taxonomy term?  What happens when you visit `/taxonomy/term/TID`?

Comment: No, /mainPage/taxonomyId is not an alias of a taxonomy term. In fact, mainPage is a panel page with several blocks and one of them is a block view.

Comment: /taxonomy/term/TID takes me to the page of the taxonomy term

Comment: I assume you're using the "grab taxonomy term ID" contextual filter.  This will not work if you aren't visiting an actual taxonomy page.  You'll need to create a custom PHP contextual filter that checks the url and then loads the corresponding TID

Comment: Is there a way to make it work without having to create a custom PHP contextual filter ?